# force VIM to use python3.6 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, vim, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and trying to use `vim` plugin that requires python3.6 (YouCompleteMe). I used `update-alternatives` to set python3.6 as the default `python` and `python3` interpreter but vim still using python3.5.
Is there a way to tell `vim` to use python3.6 interpreter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim uses the Python interpreters it was compiled with. No setting will affect it. If you can't find a Vim binary with the desired Python support, the only way to make Vim use Python3.6 is to compile it with Python3.6 yourself. See `--enable-python3interp`, `--with-python3-command` and `--with-python3-config-dir` options to Vim's `configure`.